# EXE is not Executing from Schedule Task

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

My EXE is executing perfectly fine when I am executing it by double click on it, but it is not executing when I am trying to run it via Schedule Task.

I am running schedule task on a local machine as administrator. I have already set the following settings into the "Security Options" of the Schedule Task.

1. Run only when user is logged in (I am logged in when schedule task is running)
2. Run with highest privileges check box is checked

Comment: try to specify `myEXE` with it's full path\name

Comment: @stephan Yes, I am providing the full Path and Name of the exe into the schedule task, but its still not working :-(

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it didn't worked because of the start in location of the program.
Set the [Start in] (optional) properties of the scheduled task with the path where the exe file is exist.

The default [Start in] value is C:/Windows/System32

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which Windows OS you're running this on, your EXE may have in fact started and is running in the background, with the user interface completely hidden.  Depending on the EXE you are trying to run, it may be sitting there, hidden, waiting for user input that it will never get.  If your EXE doesn't require any user input (something that just runs and then closes when it completes), then you might just check to see if the job is actually done.

A trick I have used to verify this is to create a small batch program like this:

```
@echo off
echo myEXE Scheduled Task Started %DATE% %TIME% >>c:\myEXE.log
myEXE.exe
echo myEXE Scheduled Task Completed %DATE% %TIME% >>c:\myEXE.log
```

Have your scheduled task call this batch script instead of myEXE directly.  This will generate a text file (myEXE.log) that you can check to verify when the scheduled task kicked off, and then when (and whether) the EXE finished.

Just for kicks (and to test what I'm talking about) you can add these lines at the end of the batch script.

```
pause
echo Batch Script Finished %DATE% %TIME% >>c:\myEXE.log
```

If you never see the cmd window waiting for you to `Press any key to continue...` then you'll also never see the last line in your log file (myEXE.log)

Comment: Hi @Wes Larson, I am sorry that I did not explained full situation in the question I asked. Actually, When I run exe by double clicking on it then it works perfectly fine. When I double click on it then it opens a command prompt window also creates a log file(The purpose of the exe is to look at the status of the battery of the laptop and create a log file by writing battery percentage into it). But when I run it through schedule task then only command prompt window opens but it does not create the log file(which it should create). So I can say that Schedule task is not running exe properly

Comment: I also want to tell you that exe is never expecting any input from user at all. I am also running schedule task a administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Task Scheduler is a strange beast of a program. It's not really a CRON like task scheduler and it's not a Quartz based program, other than relying on internal clock system.datetime, which has been known to have "[issues](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/6121)" of its own.

Nevertheless, it can sometimes trip over itself (unproven, but from personal observations), when it comes to permissions of a task and who created it vs what account is used to run it.

I found the following steps gives me a "clean" task schedule every time, and the task runs every time:

- Always run Task Scheduler as Administrator. If you don't have admin rights to do this, then you should even be here!
- Don't create a Basic Task. Go straight to Create Task, and under your own admin account (doesn't have to be God Admin!).
- When filling in the task wizard, don't provide a trigger UNTIL you've tested the task first. Also, make sure you've allowed the task to run whether you're logged in or not! That catches me sometimes.
- Don't worry about Settings, for now. Accept the default
- Save/OK
- Close Task Scheduler
- Restart it again, and again as Admin
- Run the task you've created.
- If all goes well, it ran! Do a CMD run of the EXE using @Wes's suggestion to be sure.
- Now, place a Trigger of your choice
- Change the Account to your proper task admin account, or a generic account with admin rights specifically created to run tasks. We call ours admin.tasks
- Save everything and you should be ok from here.